# Python: Adding elements of a tuple to an empty tuple

Tags: python, function, tuples, element

```
def oddTuples(aTup):
    '''
    aTup: a tuple

    returns: tuple, every other element of aTup. 
    '''
    num = len(aTup)
    newtup = ()
    for i in range(0,num+1):
        if (i % 2 == 1):
            newtup += aTup[i]
        else:
            continue
    return newtup
```

The function takes a tuple as an input and returns a tuple that contains the odd enteries of `aTup` i.e `aTup[1]`, `aTup[3]`,etc. On the tenth line, 
`newtup += aTup[i]`
 I receive an error. Please elaborate me why and please correct the problem. I know that there too is a single line solution to this problem but, I don't want that one. I want to know the reason and correction for my mistake on the tenth line. I'll be glad to get the help.

Comment: You can't add a tuple and number. Your line should probably be `newtup += (aTup[i],)`. Haven't checked it though. Adding the parentheses and comma turns the number into a tuple with a single member.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding the number itself to the tuple.  Only tuples can be added to tuples.  Change `newtup += aTup[i]` to `newtup += (aTup[i],)`.  That will fix the current error, but as @Rockybilly pointed out, using `range(0, num+1)` is wrong.  That will use one too many numbers.  Change it to `range(0, num)`.  You could also just leave out 0, because that is the default for `range()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
aTup[1::2]
```

should work, if aTup has at least 2 elements.

Slices are one of Python best things.

Comment: I have to note that while @zondo is correct and answers the question more fittingly since the asker didn't ask for the "one-liner solution", this answer is still the most Pythonic way to do what was asked to do.

Answer (score 0):

The `(num + 1)` in your range function is **extra**, you need only `num`.(You are getting Index error I suppose.)

```
for i in range(0,num):
    if (i % 2 == 1):
        newtup += aTup[i]
    else:
        continue
```

Yes, I oversaw the tuple error, @zondo

Comment: Well, that makes us even.  I oversaw the `range()` error :)

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are immutable, so you can't append to them.  I think appending the values to a list, and when you've finished change the list to a tuple.

```
def oddTuples(aTup):
    newlist = []
    for index, element in enumerate(aTup):
        if index % 2 == 1:
            newlist.append(element)
    return tuple(newlist)
```